# Query MongoDB for all concrete types

Tags: c#, mongodb, polymorphism

Is there a way to query for all concrete types from a collection, containing polymorphic types? In my example below `Animal` is an abstract class.

I'm aware that I can use collection.`FindAll()` which will return `BsonDocuments`, and also use the `BsonSerializer` to deserialize to the concrete type as below, but is there a generic way of doing this?

The sample below works as I currently only have `Dog` objects in my collection.

```
public List<Animal> Load(string collectionName, List<string> ids)
    {
        var results = new List<Animal>();
        var server = _client.GetServer();
        var database = server.GetDatabase(_databaseName);
        var collection = database.GetCollection(collectionName);

        foreach (var document in collection.FindAll())
        {
            results.Add(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dog>(document));
        }

        return results;            
    }
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to say something like this

```
collection.AsQueryable<Animal>().Where(c => c.Id.In(ids)).ToList();
```

but this won't work because `Animal` is **abstract**.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040584/inheritance-in-document-database