# Is there a way to handle inheritance using SimpleSchema?

Tags: meteor

I have a basic collection called Tasks. I want to create a new Collection called DailyTasks, where a DailyTask extends a Task, and also has a list of Dates on which the DailyTask was completed.

I want Tasks.findAll() to return Tasks and DailyTasks.

I would be willing to have three classes: BaseTask, OneTimeTask (which has a single dateCompleted field) and DailyTask (which has a list of datesCompleted). I would need to know how to configure my schema accordingly.

How can I do this?

Comment: This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3040584/inheritance-in-document-database

Comment: SimpleSchema refers to this as SubSchema's: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#combining-simpleschemas

Answer (score 5):

You can pass multiple schemas to the SimpleSchema constructor, and they will be combined. Like so:

```
Tasks = new SimpleSchema({ ... });

DailyTasks = new SimpleSchema([Tasks, {
  additionalField: {
    type: String
  }
}]);
```